# Initializing an array inside of adding it to an Array List

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, initialization

Hi so pretty much what I have been trying to do is create a method that is passed an Array List of Integers and returns an ArrayList of int arrays. I want each array inside of the returned Array List to contain on of the values of passed Array List. here is what I have so far

```
  public static ArrayList<int[]> createPossible(ArrayList<Integer> al)
  {
    ArrayList<int[]> returned = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++)
    {
      returned.add(new int [1]{al.get(i)});   
    }
    return returned;    
  }
```

I think that you can see the basic point of what I'm getting at here. Just cant figure out how to properly initialize each new array inside of where I'm adding it to the returned ArrayList

Comment: Remove `1` from `[1]`. Anyway would you want to create one element array? It feels like [X Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thank you for commenting, I read up on the X Y problem and I realized that I did indeed fall into this trap, in the future I will post more suited questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
new int[] {al.get(i)}
```

The length of the array is useless, since you pass a given number of values inside the curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

This will work similar to what you have described but it uses `List<Integer[]>` rather than a `List<int[]>`. If you must have `List<int[]>` then it could be augmented to suit your needs.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class StackOverflow {
    public static List<Integer[]> createPossible(List<Integer> al) {
        List<Integer[]> returned = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
            returned.add(al.toArray(new Integer[0]));
        }
        return returned;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> al = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
        List<Integer[]> result = createPossible(al);

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result.toArray()));
    }
}
```

The output of the code above:
`[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]`